# Record/playback keystrokes in textfield using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to record a user's input into an HTML textfield, and playback at a later date in realtime? One way I can think of would be to capture each keyDown event and the time delta (accurate to a few hundred ms), and store the pairs together.

Can you think of a better/more efficient way?

Comment: Do you only care about the value of the textfield in time, or do you want to record and playback *all* events? For example, if the user highlighted some text by typing `Ctrl+A`, would you want that highlighting to be visualized in the playback?

Comment: Adam, all events need to be captured and visualised.

Comment: You will find this is very difficult. Boris' and Anurag's scripts are a good start; but (as Anurag mentioned) they fail when complex keystrokes or clicks take place. One "hack" way to accomplish something which "works" in these cases, would be to periodically (on a timer) retrieve the `textfield`'s `value`, and record a time delta whenever there is a change in `value` from query to query. This will not visualize selected elements (like `Ctrl+A`, as mentioned in my previous comment), but at least it won't break as easily as the answers posted below.

Answer (score 5):

The handler which is returned by KeyDown handler contains all the informations you need to do what you want.

Try this in firebug:

```
$('#your-input').keydown(
    function(e) { 
        console.log(e.timeStamp);
        console.log(e.keyCode);
    }
);
```

You just have to store the data from the handler (var e) which has timeStamp property and keyCode.

You can then set a timer with the difference between to keydown to simulate them.